# How to deal with known generic type without boxing/unboxing

Tags: c#, generics

I have a generic method dealing with large amounts of data of various types.

I'd like to apply some additional processing when the data is a specific type (`double` in this case).  All other functionality is identical across the different types.

Is there a better way than the (very slow) box/unboxing illustrated in the example below?

This seems to imply that we need to convince the compiler that `T` and `double` are the same type, within the `if..else` section that asserts this.

```
public static T[] HalfIfDouble<T>(T[] data)
{
    T[] result;

    if (typeof(T) == typeof(double))
    {
        // result = data.Select(x => x * 0.5).ToArray(); // does not compile

        result = data.Select(x =>
        {
            double d = (double)(object)x;
            return (T)(object)(d * 0.5);
        }).ToArray();
    }
    else
    {
        result = data;
    }

    // do some more processing...

    return result;
}
```

The real functionality is obviously more complicated than this example.

Needs to work in .NET Framework and .NET 6.

Comment: Why can't you cast the entire array? i.e. `if( typeof(T) == typeof(Double) ) { return (Double[])data;` }` ?

Comment: Interesting question! Just out of curiosity: Do you actually experience a real, measurable performance issue due to boxing/unboxing here? Or are you trying to micro-optimize out of scientific curiosity (which is perfectly fine, don't get me wrong)?

Comment: Any time I see code that wants to do different things depending on the type, it raises a little red flag (just a little one) and I wonder if this whole thing could be done in a better way. It's impossible to suggest anything though, since we don't have context.

Comment: The trivial solution would be to just make the method non-generic: `double[] Half(double[] data){...}`. If this is not possible you should probably state why not in the question. And I agree with DavidG, checking the generic type is a bit of a code smell. When dealing with large amounts of data and performance is a concern I personally tend to go towards unsafe code. Including a bit more of context would probably help.

Comment: If you want to do something specific for type `double` then you should write an overload that takes type `double` and then a generic overload for everything else. The specific overload might call the generic overload internally or they might both call a third method that handles the common functionality.

Comment: @Heinzi it's definitely measurable, but not huge.  My production data has several billion values, so that's a lot of allocations.

Comment: @MarkPattison 7bn `Double` values? I trust you're using `Parallel.For` instead of using `for`, right?

Comment: @Dai we use a 120-core machine so definitely parallelise!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`as` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#as-operator) to do the casting rather than `(T)`.

- In the expression `value as T` it will attempt to cast `value` to the type `T` if it's possible, otherwise the value will be `null`.
- `as` is only available when casting to a reference type (in your case an array).

You can also use the [`is` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#is-operator) to replace the type check.

- In the expression `value is T` the expression will be true if `value` can be cast to the type `T`.
- In the expression `value as T tValue` the expression will be true if `value` can be cast to the type `T` and the variable `tValue` will be assigned the value of `(T)value`.

Updating your code with these operators we get:

- If in .Net Framework or in .Net and nullable reference types are disabled:

```
public static T[] HalfIfDouble<T>(T[] data)
{
    T[] result;

    if (data is double[] da)
    {
        result = da.Select(x => x * 0.5).ToArray() as T[];
    }
    else
    {
        result = data;
    }

    // do some more processing...

    return result;
}
```

- If in .Net and nullable reference types are enabled:
- This uses the [null-forgiving operator `!`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving) to to tell the compiler that `as T[]` will never return `null`.

  - When nullable reference types are enabled `as T[]` results in `T[]?` because if the cast fails the result is `null`.
  - We know that it won't result in `null` because we know `T` is a `double` from `data is double[]` so we can safely use this.

```
public static T[] HalfIfDouble<T>(T[] data)
{
    T[] result;

    if (data is double[] da)
    {
        result = (da.Select(x => x * 0.5).ToArray() as T[])!;
    }
    else
    {
        result = data;
    }

    // do some more processing...

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Good start, but there's a problem: because you're using `as T[];` instead of doing a C Cast (e.g. `result = (T[])( da.Select(x=>x/2f)).ToArray() );` the compiler will denote that line's expression's result type as `T[]?` not `T[]`.

Comment: @Dai it seems to denote it as `T[]`.  As arrays are reference types, I don't think `T[]?` can exist anyway.

Comment: `T[]?` would be an array reference that might be null. It's definitely a real thing.

Comment: Ah yes, in the new nullable-reference-type world.  I'd forgotten that.

Comment: Anyway, you can fix the nullable warning like this: `result = (da.Select(x => x * 0.5).ToArray() as T[])!;`

Comment: Good spot @Dai ! I've update by answer with a solution for when nullable reference types are enabled.